# Running the CorDapp (based on spring webserver) nodes on separate machines

Tags: corda

How can I deploy and run Corda nodes of spring webserver based "Yo!CorDapp" example (https://github.com/joeldudleyr3/spring-observable-stream), on separate machines?

What are the configuration changes I need to implement in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are running each server on the same machine as the node it talks to, there shouldn't be any configuration required.

Simply start the nodes on their separate machines, then start the webserver on each machine, with the [application properties](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V3/spring-observable-stream/server/src/main/resources/application.properties) modified or overridden to point to that node's RPC port.

Since the nodes are on separate machines, it's even possible to use the same RPC port for all nodes, since the IP address will differ.